# How to get a value from ajax call in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get a value from the ajax call in controller function. How can i do it?

My code is here:

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="amount_pay('{{ $res->id}}');"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
```

My script:

```
<script>

function amount_pay(id) 
         { 
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'amount_popup/'+ id,// calling the file  with id

            success: function (data) {
                alert(1);
            }
        });
      } 
</script>
```

My route:

```
Route::post('amount_popup/{id}', 'AdminController\AmountController@amount_to_pay');
```

my controller function:

```
public function amount_to_pay($id)
    {   
        echo $id;
    }
```

Comment: you can't use blade inline instead use <a  href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="amount_pay('<?php echo $res->id; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: i am not getting any error.the value not received from controller

Answer (score 0):

easly return the value:

```
public function amount_to_pay($id)
{   
    return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var url = '{{ route('amount_popup', ['id' => #id]) }}';

url = url.replace('#id', id);
```

instead of

```
'amount_popup/'+ id
```

Answer (score 0):

### You are trying to get the value from a GET request, but you are sending the form as a POST request.

You should change your script code to:

```
<script>

function amount_pay(id) 
         { 
            $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', //THIS NEEDS TO BE GET
            url:  'amount_popup/'+ id,// calling the file  with id

            success: function (data) {
                alert(1);
            }
        });
      } 
</script>
```

THEN CHANGE YOUR ROUTE TO:

```
Route::get('amount_popup/{id}', 'AdminController\AmountController@amount_to_pay');
```

#### OR IF YOU WANT TO USE POST... DO THIS...

```
<script>

function amount_pay(id) 
         { 
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:  'amount_popup',
            data: "id=" + id + "&_token={{ csrf_token() }}", //laravel checks for the CSRF token in post requests

            success: function (data) {
                alert(1);
            }
        });
      } 
</script>
```

THEN YOUR ROUTE:

```
Route::post('/amount_popup', 'AdminController\AmountController@amount_to_pay');
```

THEN YOUR CONTROLLER:

```
public function amount_to_pay(Request $request)
    {   
        return $request->input('id');
    }
```

### For more info:

[Laravel 5 Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing)